# Cant access ids from screeen class

Tags: python, kivy

so i am trying to get ids from class rule in class demoapp(MDApp)
my .py file is as follow

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ProfileScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ClientInterface(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(ProfileScreen(name='profile'))
sm.add_widget(ClientInterface(name='client'))

class demoapp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(screenhelper)
        return screen

    def logger(self):
        name = "pranav"
        password = "1234"
        id = '1'
        enname = self.root.ids.user.text
        epass = self.root.ids.password.text
        eid = self.root.ids.ID.text

        if name == enname and password == epass and id == eid:
            self.root.ids.error.text = 'Youre logged in'
            self.root.current = 'client'
            self.root.ids.user.text = ''
            self.root.ids.password.text = ''
            self.root.ids.ID.text = ''
        else:
            self.ids.error.text = 'Please enter Valid credentials'
            self.ids.user.text = ''
            self.ids.password.text = ''
            self.ids.ID.text = ''

demoapp().run()
```

and my kv file is as follow

```
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    MenuScreen:
    ProfileScreen:
    ClientInterface:

<MenuScreen>:
    name: "menu"

    Screen:
    
        Image:
            source:'images/background.jpg'
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio:False
        MDCard:
            size_hint:None, None
            size:300, 530
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
            elevation:10
            padding:25
            spacing:25
            orientation:'vertical'
            radius:30
        
            MDLabel:
                id: main
                text:"Welcome to welcome page"
                font_size:20
            MDRoundFlatButton:
                text:'Profile'
                pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
                on_press: root.manager.current ='profile'
    
<ProfileScreen>:
    name:"profile"

    Screen:
        id: some_id
    
        MDCard:
            size_hint:None, None
            size:300, 530
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
            elevation:10
            padding:25
            spacing:25
            orientation:'vertical'
            radius:30
        
            MDCard:
                size_hint:None, None
                size:250, 150
                pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
                background_color:(1,0,1,1)
                radius:20
                elevation:20
                padding:25
                spacing:25
                orientation:'vertical'
                MDLabel:
                    text:'Welcome user Please Create a Account if you are new or login if you are already a member'
                    halign:'center'
                
            MDTextFieldRound:
                id: ID
                hint_text:"ID"
                icon_right:"account-box"
                size_hint_x:None
                width:200
                font_size:18
                pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5}
                password: True
            MDTextFieldRound:
                id: user
                hint_text:"username"
                icon_right:"account"
                size_hint_x:None
                width:200
                font_size:18
                pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5}

            MDTextFieldRound:
                id: password
                hint_text:"password"
                icon_right:"eye-off"
                size_hint_x:None
                width:200
                font_size:18
                pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5}
                password: True
            
            MDLabel:
                id: error
                font_size:20
                padding_y:15
                text:''

            MDRoundFlatButton:

                text:"Submit"
                pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5}
                on_press: root.logger()
        
            GridLayout:
                cols:2
                spacing:5

                MDRoundFlatButton:
                    text:"Create New Account"
                

                MDRoundFlatButton:
                    text:"Admin login"
                    pos_hint:{"center_x":0.75}
                
<ClientInterface>:
    name:"client"
    Screen:
        id: some_id3
    
        MDCard:
            size_hint:None, None
            size:300, 530
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
            elevation:10
            padding:25
            spacing:25
            orientation:'vertical'
            radius:30
```

i cant seem to access ids from profilescreen in MDApp although i can acess them if i put logger function in ProfileScreeen class but then i cant change the screeen if the login details are correct please help me

Comment: What do you want to mean by 'screenhelper' ? Shouldn't that be something like, `Builder.load_file(some_kv_file.kv)` ?

Comment: Yeah actually that’s minor problem while copying this to stack overflow , the whole kv file is saved in string named screenhelper I didn’t copy the screen helper , but it works while running. I just need help calling ids from profile screen in main app file

Answer (score 0):

Some points I figured out,

1. You are calling `logger` from `demoapp` not from `ProfileScreen`. Thus `on_press: root.logger()` should be `on_press: app.logger()`
2. You set the `root` widget in kivy lang, so you don't need to define it again outside the app class. Same goes for the `__init__` method.
3. As your `root` is a `ScreenManager` object, you can access its individual screen by `get_screen` method. Thus you can refer `ProfileScreen` to something like `profile_screen = self.root.get_screen("profile")` and you will be able to address its own ids.

Now your `logger` method will look something like this,

```py
    def logger(self):
        name = "pranav"
        password = "1234"
        id = '1'
        profile_screen = self.root.get_screen("profile")
        enname = profile_screen.ids.user.text
        epass = profile_screen.ids.password.text
        eid = profile_screen.ids.ID.text

        if name == enname and password == epass and id == eid:
            profile_screen.ids.error.text = 'Youre logged in'
            self.root.current = 'client'
            profile_screen.ids.user.text = ''
            profile_screen.ids.password.text = ''
            profile_screen.ids.ID.text = ''
        else:
            profile_screen.ids.error.text = 'Please enter Valid credentials'
            profile_screen.ids.user.text = ''
            profile_screen.ids.password.text = ''
            profile_screen.ids.ID.text = ''
```

Though I'd suggest to create each of those attrs in the `App`'s subclass (i.e. in your `demoapp`) and then you can refer them from wherever you want.